# RSS Parser for Twitter is Slow - why?

Tags: php, twitter, rss

I am making use of [**this script**](http://pastebin.com/s4DLytLy) to get the first item of my Twitter feed. However, it is slow (it takes 3 to 4 seconds to load page now). Why is it so slow?

Here is how I use it.

```
require_once 'rss_php.php'; //see link above

$rss = new rss_php;

$rss->load('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/XXXXXX.rss');

$feed = $rss->getItems(false, 1);

echo $feed[0]['title'];
echo $feed[1]['title'];
```

I do get this PHP notice:

> Notice: Undefined variable: tempNode
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\rss_php.php
>   on line 137

I don't know why since this works, line 137 is this line:

```
return $tempNode;
```

Thanks all for any help. I appreciate any advice on speeding this up.

Comment: where do you define/set `$tempNode`?

Comment: You can solve PHP notice by adding $tempNode = array(); before the foreach line on 102.

Comment: It works for me just fine. Not slow at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, line 110 of your pastbin is assigning a variable that was never declared. As such, any requests or assignments to an undeclared variable will do this. From what I see it should be as simple as adding `$tempNode = Array();` just below the function call of the extractDOM method.

Next, since this is a script from someone else I would recommend asking them what you can do to improve performance. From what is in the pastbin I don't see anything elaborate going on, nor do I see you using the library incorrectly, but ultimately they would know better.

Comment: I have done that now, but the weird thing I get the same error but the line number points to the same place which is a `}` as everything has shifted down!

Answer (score 3):

Fetching content from a remote location can potentially introduce some rather ugly loading issues.

Try saving the contents of the RSS feed in a local file and see if the problem persists when loading from a local drive. 
If this fixes the issue, you should look into caching the contents of the feed every once in a while.

Comment: If all else fails, profiling your script with tools like Xdebug could help you find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

After line 138 in rss_php.php (v.1 Free version) file paste this:

```
...
if (!isset($tempNode)){
    $tempNode = null;
}
return $tempNode;
...
```

Enjoy

;)

Answer (score -2):

Getting rid of that return $tempNode; notice is easy, but not your problem, it just needs to be defined out of the forloop in that extractDOM function.

Optimizing your php code is a big task.  I'm assuming that the api call is the majority of the time, but if you want to try and speed your code up a bit I would look into tutorials on how to do that:

http://ilia.ws/archives/12-PHP-Optimization-Tricks.html

http://progtuts.info/55/php-optimization-tips/

http://hungred.com/useful-information/php-micro-optimization-tips/

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I don't agree with his first part, but the later seems to be good.

Comment: My answer is still correct. A PHP Notice is just a warning.  Just because it's bad code doesn't make it not work.  The question was about performance.